# Customizing Hair Vertex Group Data/Links

Tags: drivers, vertex-groups, hair

Blender allows density and a few other properties (ex. clump) to be tied to vertex groups. However, I was wondering if there is a way to tie other properties such as the "roundness" property to a vertex group. (Ideal situation would be to control the "roundness" property in interpolation mode, while it only exists in simple children mode.) Would it be done through drivers, or datablocks somehow, or scripts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Karl! Great questions. I will say that BSE _strongly_ recommends only asking one question per post. If you could __edit__ your question, delete the second question, and ask it in a separate post, that would be fantastic! BSE is a tremendous and powerful forum. If you haven't already taken the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), please consider doing so. We'd all like you to be a part of it!

Comment: sorry, I'll remove one question

Comment: @Karl it don't think this is possible at the moment, the todo list of blender 2.8 mentions alot of new features for the particle system. so maybe one of them include allowing more properties to be controlled by vertex groups and textures.